# Resize bitmap like ImageView scaleType="center"

Tags: java, android

How to resize bitmap like ImageView scaleType="center"
I try to do so

```
 Bitmap srcBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(adImagePath);
 Bitmap dstBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcBmp, 100, 100, true);
```

but get the effect scaleType="centerCrop"

the image should be resized but should not be compressed

Thanks